# How to reply "I am busy"?

Tags: phrases

"Hello, how are you?"
"Sorry, I am up to my neck now. I'll come back to you in a minute."
"?"

The phrase "take your time" comes to my mind, eventhough I don't know why. Maybe sometime someone once said that to me. How can I reply in such scenarios?

Comment: *Sorry, **can't stop!** I'm on my way to hospital to be treated for a snake-bite!*

Comment: "Take your time" is a common reply. Simply saying, "No problem. I'm not in a rush/hurry." would be fine, or  "I can wait," would convey the same thing.

Comment: Are you texting?  On the phone? In a chat window? I ask because **come back to you** is odd for a spoken conversation, unless you're putting a phone caller on hold.

Comment: It's happening in a chat window.